# Как перенести уже написанный код на Фрагменты?

Tags: android

Допустим, я создал какую-то программу. Но запутался в файлах активити. Одна часть отображается правильно, а другая совсем иначе. Не могу отображать нужную вещь в нужном месте. Всё превратилось в кашу.

Погуглив, прочитал о фрагментах. Но не знаю как разбить уже готовый код на куски.

Как это сделать? Как перенести готовую рабочую программу на фрагменты?

Comment: В какой IDE проект?

Comment: Боюсь никто кроме вас не знает как разбить ваш код на куски. Ваш вопрос слишком общий для этого ресурса.

Comment: проект на Android Studio. Но хоть что то общее сказать могут. Главная часть лежит на MainActivity. Что мне с ней делать, куда перенести, еще есть другие классы. Будут ли они работать если их вызовут из фрагмента. Вот эти вещи сказать могут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поможет или нет, не знаю. Совсем недавно, неделю назад, я переписывал свою программу под фрагменты. Раньше было все в MainActivity. Захотелось все перенести на отдельные листы где в каждом была какая то часть из старого активити. Что я делал? Сначала просто добавил эти самые фрагменты и все что вызывало ошибку закоменитровал. Далее частями переносил. Возникали проблемы-вопросы как обращаться к методам активити из фрагмента или наоборот. При помощи поиска находил все ответы. Медленно но верно все перенеслось. Думал, что не получится, но за 3 дня справился, чего и вам желаю.